# Get unique names from table colum

Tags: org-mode, org-table

I have one table (TBL1), I want to generate another table with unique items from TBL1.
Currently, I can do it with elisp as below but I think it's too complicate.

```
#+NAME: TBL1
| Item | Amount |
|------+--------|
| A    |    100 |
| B    |     20 |
| A    |    120 |
| C    |     40 |
| B    |     50 |
| A    |     20 |
| C    |     16 |
|------+--------|
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var x=TBL1[1:-1] :results output raw :exports both
  (let (y)
    (dolist (line x)
      (setq y (append y (list (car line)))))
    (setq y (delete-dups y))
    (dolist (elem y)
      (princ (format "|%s|\n" elem))))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| A |
| B |
| C |
```

I can find a similar unique API from the document.what's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :var x=TBL1[1:-1] 
  (delete-dups (mapcar (lambda (y) (list (car y))) x))
#+END_SRC
```

Its similar to your code, but with a functional programming (rather than imperative) approach.

`(list (car y))` returns rows with only the first element of the original rows. `mapcar` applies this function to the whole list of rows.

Note that the result is the list, which org-mode automatically interprets and converts to a table. No need to explicitly format it.

Comment: What would you change in the code if you would want to show the 2d column instead of the 1st?

Comment: @crocefisso Replace `car` for `cadr`. This is: [the first element of the rest of the list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Elements.html).

Comment: Thank you for your help @Juancho ! It allowed me to find the solution. Actually, I needed to show the 5th column: `(delete-dups (mapcar (lambda (y) (list (nth 4 y))) x))`